# Backbone template variables only working with if I use this in template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, asset-pipeline, eco, jst

In my template I have to put this.name and this.gravatar  to access my user model data attributes.
If I don't I get an error message when the template attempts to render.  Everything works but I don't see any examples where they put this. in the templates.

My Backbone View:

```
Class MyApp.Views.Header extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['header']

  initialize: =>
    @model.on("change reset add", @render)

  render: =>
    @$el.html(@template (@model.attributes) )
    this
```

My Header Template:

```
<span id= "headerRight">
  <span>
    <a href="/classroom/help">Help</a>
  </span>
  <span> <img id="headerGravatar" src="<%= this.gravatar %>"></span>
  <span> <%= this.name %> </span>
  <span>
    <a class="logout" href='/signout'>Sign Out</a>
  </span>
</span>
```

How I generate my view:

```
headerView = new UCBCloudClassroom.Views.Header( model: @user)
    $('#header').html(headerView.render().el)
```

Comment: Correct I am saying <%= this.name %> works but <%= name %> doesn't.  I took out the space in the render method.  Still no difference.  I get the error message name is not defined when the template tries to render.  If I just change the template code to this.name it works fine.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with using the rails asset pipeline and the template is in a jst.eco file.  I get an error in the javascript console  saying name is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone requires underscore so most of the examples you see will use underscore templates which have the <%= property %> syntax.

Eco templates use the <%= @property %> syntax for displaying model attributes [link](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco):

Since <%= @property %> is equivalent to <%= this.property %> everything is working as intended.